# SQL Query help - how to group number of entries

Tags: sql

Given the following data, I would like to count the **number of items in each group (defined by groupid) and need to filter by templateid, but not consider multiple versions from itemversion**

Basically I can get all the information I need and have the query to pull this data from the ItemVersion table, but need to be able to join with the Item table in order to filter by templateid.

```
Item - PK = id + cultureid
id            cultureid     templateid      
1             1             5
1             2             5
2             1             4
2             2             4
2             3             4
3             1             5
4             1             7
4             1             11

ItemVersion (PK = id + cultureid + versionid)
id            cultureid     versionid     groupid 
1             1             1             11
1             2             2             11 
1             2             3             11 
1             2             4             11 
2             1             5             6
2             2             6             6
2             3             7             6
3             1             8             8
4             1             9             9
5             1             10            11
```

---

SQL to pull the data but **not aggregated properly to remove multiple versions**:

```
SELECT ItemVersion.groupid COUNT(ItemVersion.id) as VersionCount 
    FROM itemVersion iv JOIN ITEM i ON i.id = iv.cultureid AND iv.CultureId = i.CultureId 
        WHERE i.TemplateId != 11
            GROUP BY iv.groupid
                ORDER BY VersionCount desc
```

**Sample Output:**

```
6      3
8      1
9      1 
11     1
```

**Update - This did the trick:**
*Thanks to Branko for pointing me in the right direction*

```
select ccv.WorkgroupID, COUNT(*) AS ArticleCount FROM ItemVersion ccv 
      JOIN Item cc ON
            CCV.Id = cc.Id AND CCV.CultureId = CC.CultureId

      WHERE 
      CCV.versionid in ( --Use latest version only for counts
                  select (MAX(ccv.versionid)) 
                        from ItemVersion ccv 
                              group by ccv.Id, ccv.CultureId
            )
      GROUP BY ccv.GroupId
      ORDER BY ArticleCount DESC
```

Comment: Can you show some sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to count the **latest versions** of items per group (and completely skip non-latest versions)?

If so, the following query should do the job:

```
SELECT groupid, COUNT(*)
FROM ItemVersion IV1
WHERE
    versionid = (
        SELECT MAX(versionid)
        FROM ItemVersion IV2
        WHERE IV1.id = IV2.id AND IV1.cultureid = IV2.cultureid
    )
GROUP BY groupid
```

If you need to filter on additional criteria from `Item`, you can easily join it into the query. For example:

```
SELECT groupid, COUNT(*)
FROM ItemVersion IV1 JOIN Item I ON IV1.id = I.id AND IV1.cultureid = I.cultureid
WHERE
    I.templateid <> 11
    AND versionid = (
        SELECT MAX(versionid)
        FROM ItemVersion IV2
        WHERE IV1.id = IV2.id AND IV1.cultureid = IV2.cultureid
    )
GROUP BY groupid
```